# Interpolated opacity is not initially invisible

Tags: reactjs, react-native-reanimated

I am trying to create an interpolation on opacity. I create the clock, and decide the start time and end time of the animation. I interpolate it so it starts at 0, however my view is visible. Do you know why it's visible? Is it the clock is created not at default of 0 but of current time? Is it possible to initialize my `animStartTime` at the same value as clock?

Here is an expo showing the problem and code and screenshot below. We see a black square of 48x48. It should be invisible but its at full 100% opacity.

https://snack.expo.io/@noitidart/reanimated-interpolation-not-initially-invisible

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import Reanimated from 'react-native-reanimated';

export default function App() {
  const animClock = new Reanimated.Clock();

  // determine the times it will run from
  const duration = 1400;
  const animStartTime = new Reanimated.Value(0);
  const animEndTime = Reanimated.add(animStartTime, duration);

  // create the opacity
  const animFrom = new Reanimated.Value(0);
  const animTo = new Reanimated.Value(1);
  const opacity = Reanimated.interpolate(animClock, {
    inputRange: [animStartTime, animEndTime],
    outputRange: [animFrom, animTo],
    extrapolate: Reanimated.Extrapolate.CLAMP,
  });

  return (
    <View style={{ justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', flex: 1 }}>
      <Reanimated.View
        style={{ width: 48, height: 48, backgroundColor: 'black', opacity }}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I modified some part of your code and you can see it [there](https://snack.expo.io/VfIl-rlMC)

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I'm looking at diff now, its quite a few changes. Do you know what exactly fixed it. I'm still diffing and experimenting.

Comment: @Noitidart Tell me which part is unclear for you and I'll explain it

Comment: Thanks, so I commented out the `useCode` block, and your code has same issue as mine. Before the animation runs, the block is at opacity 1. It should be 0. Is it possible to fix this?

Comment: Can you share snack?

Comment: Take a look at a great tutorial [here](https://codedaily.io/courses/7/React-Native-Reanimated-Fundamentals/132). There is explained in detail how reanimated works

Comment: Thank you Leri for trying to help. My original snack has the problem. Also in your snack if you just comment out the "useCode" block you will see the rectangle on your screen with opacity 1. It should be opacity 0 to start.

Comment: I completely removed `useCode` block entirely but the app works as expected, `useCode ` just detects when the animation is finished and stops the timer